# SNMPTT and perl snmp module troubleshooting

Tags: perl, unix, snmp, net-snmp, snmp-trap

I'm on centos6.7 and i need to install `snmptt` to get all SNMP traps and log them into Nagios. I made it work yesterday, but today, not the same story...

I've run the `yum install perl-Net-SNMP` command, it told me that the package is already installed (from epel)
I've enabled the module on the snmptt.ini and now, when i'm trying to run it, I've a failed message :

```
root@SLINUX01:[~]$service snmptt restart
Stopping snmptt:                                           [FAILED]
Starting snmptt: Can't locate SNMP.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at (eval 12) line 1.

Could not load the Perl module SNMP!  If net_snmp_perl_enable is
enabled then the SNMP module is required.  Please see snmptt.html
for system requirements.  Note:  SNMPTT uses the Net-SNMP package's
SNMP module, NOT the CPAN Net::SNMP module!

died at /usr/sbin/snmptt line 426.
```

Suggestions ?

Comment: Does not look like a programming question. Looks like a question about network management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution : just install a different package :

yum install net-snmp-perl  =/= yum install perl-Net-SNMP

Answer (score 0):

The provided solution also worked for `SNMPTT` on *Oracle Linux 7.5*.

```
yum install net-snmp-perl
```

worked for me.